# getAttribute(value) method returns null, even though the value exists in HTML; Selenium, JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, getattribute

I am testing an element(button) that sorts(asc or desc) a dynamic table that is part of the website. Was trying to receive value from attribute **aria-label** with getAttribute() method, but it always returns null. The value at this attribute exists, I just replaced it with "some value", so I don't understand why this happens?

HTML snippet:

```
<th class="class name" tabindex="0" aria-controls="my-discussions-table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 3%;" aria-label="some value">ID</th>
```

Java code:

```
if(sortID.getAttribute("aria-label").equals("some value")) {...}
```

SortID is the element I am testing that does the sorting part. In this line of code getAttribute("aria-label") returns null and NullPointerException pops up.

Comment: Probably it's set by js and it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more detailed?

Comment: In other words if your code runs before the javascript framework adds those attributes, it won't be there yet.

Comment: **NullPointerException** sounds more serious then `getAttribute("aria-label")`, address NPE first